# Android ListView App crash error

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I tries to set up a listView in a fragment but my app crashes,tried to search on the internet but couldn't find an answer.

**Java Source code:**

```
public static class FragmentFind extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String [] cinemas={
                "Cinema 1","Cinema 2","Cinema 3"
        };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cinemas);

        ListView list=(ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cinema_list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find,container,false);

    }

}
```

**Android XML layout for the fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cinema_list"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is the exception and where does it occurs in the code?

Comment: it shows nothing in the IDE(intellij Idea) but the app just crashes.

Comment: It probably shows `NullPointerException` and you miss it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your ListView is Null. As your Listview is part of Fragment layout you have to call `findViewById()` on view inflated by that fragment layout file.

So try like,

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find,container,false);

        String [] cinemas={"Cinema 1","Cinema 2","Cinema 3"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cinemas);

        ListView list=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.cinema_list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is probably a null exception. The main differences that I saw from my fragment from yours.

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whatever, container, false);
    View testview= (View) v.findViewById(R.id.id);
    return v;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your activity does not have the `ListView` `R.id.cinema_list` when the app tries to search for it by: `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cinema_list);`

So you should better search the `ListView` within inflated view by:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find,container,false);
ListView myList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.cinema_list);
```

And then set the adapter and return the `view` .

You are lucky that your app crashed. It is also possible that `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cinema_list)` could find a `ListView` if your activity layout has a `ListView` with `R.id.cinema_list`. I am telling this because it is obvious that you will have only one `ListView` with such specific id, but sometimes people use common ids such as `listView1`. So you better be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
ListView list=(ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cinema_list);
```

with this:

```
ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.cinema_list);
```

Comment: Thanks,that was the problem and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look at the Difference between `onCreateView()` and `onViewCreated()` in Fragment.Even tough you can do do the same thing in `onCreateView()` method, it is best to do the setting of the Adapter in the `onViewCreated()` method

This is where the issue is,

```
ListView list=(ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cinema_list);
```

Here is how I would do it.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find,container,false);

    }



    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    String [] cinemas={
                    "Cinema 1","Cinema 2","Cinema 3"
            };
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cinemas);

            ListView list=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.cinema_list);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```